Как выгрузить больше 100 постов через VK API?
Всем привет!
Есть код на Питоне, он выглядит следующим образом. Цель этого кода - подцепиться к ссылкам из df'a и выгрузить из них текст. Но к сожалению, он выгружает всего 100 строк, когда в оригинальном df'e их около 4 тыс.
from vk_api import VkApi
from vk_api.exceptions import ApiError
import re
import pandas as pd

token = 1111

vk_session = VkApi(token=token)
vk = vk_session.get_api()

df1 = pd.read_excel (r'C:\Users\Bot\Downloads\1.xlsx')

# Функция для извлечения идентификатора поста из ссылки
def extract_post_id(url):
    match = re.search(r'wall(-?\d+_\d+)', url)
    if match:
        return match.group(1)
    return None

# Список ссылок на посты
post_urls = df1 ['Ссылка на пост'] 

# Извлекаем идентификаторы постов
post_ids = [extract_post_id(url) for url in post_urls if extract_post_id(url)]

# Получаем текст постов
try:
    posts = vk.wall.getById(posts=','.join(post_ids))
    for post in posts:
        df = pd.DataFrame(posts)

except ApiError as e:
    print(f"Ошибка: {e}")

df.to_excel (r'C:\Users\Bot\Desktop\БД\данные.xlsx', index=False)


Как прописать условие, что бы запрос к API выгружал мне больше 100 строк? Насколько я понял, тут нужно как то запустить execute с циклом, но не понимаю как прописать:(
Буду благодарен за любое решение

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример
